# Delegate authentication token from react app to express app with OpenID and passportjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, openid

I am using the OpenID client to authenticate the user, what I would like to do is call a protected route on an express API.

I am trying to share the authorization cookie obtained with the react app with OpenID, and the x[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk34z.png)

I tried:

simply passport.authenticate(), with the openID strategy, but does redirection which isnt necessary

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way but, this is how I kinda did it:

```
const user = await auth0Client.getUser();
          // Attach token
const accessToken = await auth0Client.getTokenSilently();
axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
```

Then I just used the passport JWT strategy combined with jwks-rsa library to obtain the secret.